# Unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" c++ in Netbeans 7.2

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans, c++11, netbeans-7.2

I am trying to use C++11. After sifting through the internet I found that all I have to do is
right click on my project -> properties and under the "C++ standard" select c++ 11.  When I run the program with C++ 11, I get this error "unrecognized command line option `-std=c++11`.  One solution people have said is to add `-g -std=c++0x` in the "Additional Options" but then I get "unrecognized command line option `-std=c++0x`.  I have downloaded gcc-4.7.1.tar.gz but I have no idea what to do with it.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error or know how to make net beans compile with c++11?

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using?  Superficially, it appears to be one that does not, in fact, recognize the C++11 standard.  If your version is older than 4.7, that is quite plausible.  Check with `gcc --version`.

Comment: If you've downloaded the source for GCC 4.7.1, you now need to build it. This is a modestly complex operation.  You'll need to make sure you have sufficiently recent versions of the GMP, MPFR and MPC libraries (or build them — in the correct order, which is GMP, MPFR, MPC, if I remember correctly). With those installed, you then create a directory `gcc-4.7.1-obj` where you have `gcc-4.7.1` (the extracted source), and `cd gcc-4.7.1-obj`. Then you run `../gcc-4.7.1/configure` (adding whatever options are necessary), followed by `make bootstrap`. It is a good idea to log the build.

Comment: There are a lot of options that you might need to provide to configure, and there are endless things that might go wrong, too.  The outline steps above are no more than that — an outline (and an optimistic outline at that).  Note that you need several gigabytes of spare space to build GCC (less than 4 spare GiB might cause trouble).

Comment: Depending on your operating system, there should be a way to install a newer gcc without having to build it from source. What OS are you using?

Comment: Your question seems to be either "How do I install gcc 4.7?" or "How do I select an installed compiler in Netbeans 7.2?"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That seems really complex.  I can try it though.  Then how do I get an IDE that can run C++11?

Comment: @KeithThompson I am running windows 7.  I managed to get NEtbeans up and running using gcc by following http://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions.html

Comment: It is moderately complex.  If everything goes smoothly, it is a little time consuming, but the computer does it all; if anything goes wrong, you need experience to resolve it.  I've built it on both Linux (RHEL 5— don't ask) and Mac OS X 10.7.4, and I've built previous versions of GCC on various machines over the years.  As Keith suggested, maybe you should just find a pre-built GCC 4.7.1.  It'll be available for your platform, almost certainly.

Comment: As for IDE, I'm not sure; I've yet to find an IDE that I understand, much less like.

Comment: I'll try then searching for a pre-built GCC 4.7.1 and see where my search takes me.

Answer (score 4):

bump your gcc version to 4.7+. c++0x is supported since gcc4.3 while c++11 is supported since gcc4.7

Answer (score -2):

Steps to configure through Netbeans IDE:

1. Right click on project and goto properties
2. Go to Build -> C++Compiler
3. In right hand side panel there are few options
   go to Basic options -> C++ Standard
   change its value from C++ 11 to C++ 98