# Why would Netbeans not recognize forward_list in my C++ application?

Tags: c++, netbeans

Netbeans marks any instances of `forward_list` in my C++ application with a red line (The error is `Unable to resolve identifier forward_list`). Netbeans also does not recognize any methods that the `forward_list` instances have.

My program, however, compiles just fine. Furthermore, autocomplete for `#include <forward_list>` works.

How do I tell Netbeans to recognize the C++ standard library while checking for syntax and for autocomplete aside from preprocessor includes?

Comment: Does this happen with other C++11 features like `<regex>`, `<random>` or `<chrono>`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, it does happen. For instance, after `#include<chrono>`, `system_clock::now()` is unrecognized, and I am using the standard namespace.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Netbeans, however, perhaps this post will help (except changing from C++98/03 to C++11 instead of the other way around): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377358/unrecognized-command-line-option-std-c11-c-in-netbeans-7-2

Comment: Thanks! That did! I had to go to Project -> Properties -> Code Assistance -> C++ Standard and then change the standard to C++11. If you answer, I'll give you credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly stolen from another post, but changing the standard to `C++11` should fix this:

Project -> Properties -> Code Assistance -> C++ Standard -> C++11.